# Is there a way to dynamically update App Engine dispatch rules?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

It seems App Engine dispatch rules are configured at the project level, totally static, and must be defined as a complete configuration? If so that is really inflexible so I'm hoping that's not the case.

I want to be able to dynamically create/deploy/destroy app engine apps with a custom domain - how is that even supposed to work?

For example user1 is working on appOne. They should be able to deploy their own instance of appOne to test. user2 is also working on the app and they should be able to deploy their own instance and these instances should be accessible at paths they choose.

How do I automate these deploys? I want to deploy an app and *add* a dispatch rule dynamically. So there is a script that can do this `./deploy --instance-name=user1-test`. An instance gets deployed and it's accessible at `mycompany.com/appOne/user1-test`.

How is that possible? Is there an API call you can make to just *add* a route? Or in order to do something like this you would need to programmatically generate and apply a dispatch.yaml? That would be terrible and probably not reliable because it would clobber all existing rules every time it is applied.

### Edit

Maybe there is some advanced URL rewriting that might make this kind of dynamic thing possible? So I could say match URL `mycompany.com/appOne/user1-test` to a service named `appOne/user1-test`? That's all I want really.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the App Engine Admin API to update the dispatch rules dynamically.

The dispatch rules are part of the `apps` resource.

Take a look at [this link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps) for more information.